# How do I test for a empty string/null, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I test for a input[text] field that has nothing in?

This is what I have so far:

```
    if ($('#StartingPrice').length == ""){
        alert("ERROR!");
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
if ($('#StartingPrice')[0].value.length == 0){
    alert("ERROR!");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`$('#StartingPrice').length` returns an integer so it will never equal `""`.

Try using the `val()` method:

```
if($('#StartingPrice').val() == "")
{
    alert("ERROR!");
}
```

---

[.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

> The number of elements in the jQuery object.

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

[.value](http://api.jquery.com/value)

> No Such jQuery Method Exists

Comment: 10 seconds. You must have cheated.

Comment: @Raynos - Please there is no race here. We all here to help each other. There is no competition.

Comment: @Naveed thank you for standing up for me, some times users like Raynos can make people sad, but I try to stay positive, mostly through meditation and deep breathing.

Comment: @Hunter 8 answers? What's going on. @NaveedAhman there is a race. I have to beat Hunter!

Comment: I usually have a mental break down and rock in the fetal position under my desk, sobbing, as it's traumatizing to have someone answer before you.

Comment: @hunter I read it as intended to be quite a light-hearted comment

Answer (score 3):

Just as an alternative to the already provided solutions... you could also use a Regex to test that it actually contains something other than whitespace.

```
!!$('#StartingPrice').val().match(/\S/)
```

This will test for the existing of a non-whitespace character and using the Not-Not will convert it to a Boolean value for you. True if it contains non-whitespace. False if blank or only whitespace.

Comment: you would still need to use `val()` not `value()`

Comment: Edited from value() to val().

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#StartingPrice').val() === ""){
    alert("ERROR!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#StartingPrice').val() == ""){
    alert("ERROR!");
}
```

If the value of your text input is any empty string then it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
if ($('#StartingPrice').val() == false) {
    alert("Error!");
}
```

Use the .val() method to get the value and then pass that into the if. If the string is empty or white space it will evaluate to false.

Comment: Fixed, I was typing too fast!

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
if(myStr){
   // Your code here
}
```

Comment: if there were a "Reject" option this would def win